# My netbeans project provides error when executed by the green run button on top

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, netbeans

I created a netbeans project and replaced its index.html file with my own index.jsp and deleted index.html file but now when I m trying to run through the green run button in the bar it runs and shows,"the content requested is not found". I thought that index.jsp would be run but its not happening. If all other pages are run separately, then project runs smooth without errors. Is there a possible solution to this problem: i.e., when i click the green run button all project runs with index.jsp as the default page?

Comment: post your `web.xml` or change `index.html` to `index.jsp` under tag `welcome-file-list`

Comment: What type of project did you create? Please tell the value for `Categories` and `Projects` if you would create a new one using the project wizard.

Comment: Welcome-file-list in web.xml?

Comment: I created a web application under J2EE projects category @SubOptimal

Comment: Does it also happen if you create a new project like this or only in the other project? I tried it locally (categories: Java Web and porjects: Web Application in the wizard) with default settings for the project and if the file `web/index.html` is replaced by a `web/index.jsp` the JSP page is displayed instead.